# Manual closing of Session from hibernate when using JPA and Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, jpa, batch-processing

If I wish to use batch inserts I believe I have to handle that with hibernate as it is not supported by the JPA. My question is about how I should handle the session. For example:

```
@Transactional
public void persistData() {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            CRR crr = new CRR();
            session.save(crr);
            if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { 
                session.flush();
                session.clear();
            }
        }
}
```

Is it neccessary for me to:

```
session.close();
```

at the end of the method or is it fine to rely on the session being closed at the end of the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing Hibernate-specific in what you are trying to achieve, the same basic operations are supported in JPA:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    CRR crr = new CRR();
    entityManager.persist(crr);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { 
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
    }
}
```

And since there is nothing unusual in this code you also don't need to do anything for manual session handling.

Perhaps you confused this pattern with different approach to batch operations using a `StatelessSession`, which is Hibernate-specific and requires manual session management.